# excel: How do I run my VLookup formula only if certain criteria is met?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I want to create a formula that checks if there is a name above it before it returns a number from the table.

For example, when I put 4180 under PAUL in Cell D33; cells E33:I33 will show 200. In my example below, for Level 4, there isn't a name but a number is still showing in cell I38. I do not want it to display a number.

I tried to use Vlookup function, but do not know how to make cell blank when there is no name.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the functions =IF and =ISTEXT OR =ISBLANK to check if a name is populated. If a name is populated you can have it run your Vlookup formula to pull the numbers from the table.

```
=If(ISTEXT(D2)=TRUE,VLOOKUP(.....),"")
```

Where D2 is referencing the cell above to check for a name and the Vlookup formula is to check your table.

This statement is saying if the above cell has text, run the Vlookup formula, if false, leave the cell blank.

Here are my results.

```
=If(ISTEXT(D2)=TRUE,VLOOKUP($C$3,$J$2:$O$5,2,FALSE),"")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3LAF.png)
[image]

Comment: In my screenshot I did not run the foruma under "Level 4", but I can assure you it will work. It will not return a number if there is no name in the cell above.